# Not able to connect to any network wireless/wired

Tags: network-manager, internet

my nm-applet is not showing up. Thus I am not able to connect to any network. i have tried all the solution related to nm-applet but still it's not showing up.I am new to Ubuntu . Even my top panel has disappeared where we can select the network we want to connect. Also since I am not able to connect to internet I am unable tu run commands that requires the internet connection to solve this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Comment: Please write down the results of requested commands so that you can manually post them here. We can't help you without a few clues.

Comment: cat /etc/networks/ interfaces OUTPUT- (auto lo & iface lo inet loopback)

Comment: @Pilot6  have commented the output for that command do check it and also I was going through a couple of ans that asked to edit some files in /etc/NetworkManager but this directory doesn't contain any file in my case

Comment: @chili555 have commented the output

Comment: Does the applet reappear if you do: `nm-applet &` in the terminal?

Comment: @chili555 No it doesn't come the Output -( Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-lKcI7GL9UK: Connection Failed) Also there is no menu bar where the wifi icon and date time used to appear .